# 404 Not Found error when running ServiceStack on IIS8

Tags: servicestack, iis-8, servicestack-bsd

My ServiceStack web service works fine in IIS Express (VS 2012) and when deployed to Windows Azure, but it does not work under IIS 8 on Window 8.

I am getting `404 Not Found Error`.  My `web.config` has both sections defined for IIS Express and the web server.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

### Solution:

Just figured out, through further research, that this resolved my problem:

1. I switched the application pool to *Integrated Mode*.
2. I added the following to `web.config`:

   ```xml
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
   </system.webServer>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Repeating the solution as an answer, to make it clear what the issue was:

---

by doing some more searching i found 2 suggestions that resolved my problem:

1. switched application pool to Integrated mode
2. added the following to web.config

   ```
    <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   ```

Comment: there is something else I also noticed that i should mention about the problem. Once I update servicestack using nuget to a latest version the problem reappears again, but this time it is cause by the fact that reference to System.Web.Razor.Unofficial component get removed. To fix that I had to Install-Package System.Web.Razor.Unofficial package and add reference to that dll from the project. again I am using w8 and vs.net 2012, hope it will save some time to someone ;~)

Comment: I've noticed sometimes NuGet updates don't work properly, i.e. they don't include all the libraries in the package. When this happens I manually delete all the NuGet references and packages and start from scratch again.